# Clean up my jQuery code on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, code-cleanup

I'm doing some form validation on a job application and adding a class when an element is not filled out properly. I've got some html and jQuery below that is removing that class from a particular set of elements, if the applicant checks a "do not self-identify" checkbox. I am having trouble finding out a cleaner way of referencing the spans. I also included portion of an "onclick" event that I have triggered on the "do not self-identify" checkbox that disables the same elements that I am removing the class from. In that section of code you will see some commented out lines where I was unsuccessful in referencing the spans. Any help would be awesome! Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<tr class="TrLight">
    <td colspan="2" valign="top">
        <table>
            <tr class="TrLight" id="areYouHispanic">
                <td width="55%" valign="top"><b>1. Are you Hispanic or Latino?</b> A person of Cuban, Mexican, Chicano/a, Puerto Rican, South or Central American, or other Spanish culture or origin, regardless of race.
                </td>
                <td width="45%" valign="top" class="LeftSidePadding">
                    <span id="AAI_Hispanic_Span">
                        <input type="radio" name="AAI_Hispanic" id="hispanicLatinoYes" onClick="disableRace('hispanicLatinoYes')" value="Yes"></input>
                        <label for="hispanicLatinoYes">Yes (Skip to question #3)<br /></label>
                        <input type="radio" name="AAI_Hispanic" id="hispanicLatinoNo" onClick="disableRace('hispanicLatinoYes')" value="No"></input>
                        <label for="hispanicLatinoNo">No (Go to question #2)</label>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="IdentificationWhatRace" id="whatRace">
    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><b>2. What race or races do you consider yourself to be? (Check all that apply)</b><br /><br />
        <span class="formCheckbox" id="AAI_Race_Span">
            <input type="checkbox" name="AAI_White" id="AAI_White" value="Yes"></input>
            <label for="AAI_White"><b>White:</b> a person having origins in any of the original peoples of Europe, the Middle East, or North Africa<br /></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="AAI_Black" id="AAI_Black" value="Yes"></input>
            <label for="AAI_Black"><b>Black or African American:</b> a person having origins in any of the black racial groups of Africa<br /></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="AAI_PacificIslander" id="AAI_PacificIslander" value="Yes"></input>
            <label for="AAI_PacificIslander"><b>Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander:</b> a person having origins in any of the original peoples of Hawaii, Guam, Samoa, or other Pacific Islands<br /></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="AAI_Asian" id="AAI_Asian" value="Yes"></input>
            <label for="AAI_Asian"><b>Asian:</b> a person having origins in any of the original peoples of the Far East, Southeast Asia, or the Indian subcontinent including, for example, Cambodia, China, India, Japan, Korea, Malaysia, Pakistan, the Philippine Islands, Thailand, and Vietnam<br /></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="AAI_AmericanIndianAlaskanNative" id="AAI_AmericanIndianAlaskanNative" value="Yes"></input>
            <label for="AAI_AmericanIndianAlaskanNative"><b>American Indian or Alaskan Native:</b> a person having origins in any of the original peoples of North and South America (including Central America), and who maintains tribal affiliation or community attachment</label>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="TrLight" id="whatGender">
    <td valign="top">
        <b>3. What is your gender?</b>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <span id="AAI_Gender_span">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="whatGenderMale" value="Male">
            <label for="whatGenderMale">Male <br /></label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="whatGenderFemale" value="Female">
            <label for="whatGenderFemale">Female</label>
        </span>
    </td>    
</tr>

<tr class="TrDark">
    <td colspan="2" valign="top">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="noSelfIdentify" id="noSelfIdentify" value="Yes" onClick="disableIdentification('noSelfIdentify')">I do not wish to Self-Identify</input>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('#noSelfIdentify').click(function(){
    jQuery(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[93].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[1]).removeClass("campuri-necesare");
    jQuery(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[94].children[0].children[3]).removeClass("campuri-necesare");
    jQuery(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[95].children[1]).removeClass("campuri-necesare");
});
```

On Click Disable JS:

```
function disableIdentification(xRadioButton) {
if (document.getElementById(xRadioButton).checked){


    // jQuery('#AAI_White').parentNode.classList.remove("campuri-necesare");
    // document.getElementById('AAI_Hispanic_Span').classList.remove("campuri-necesare");
    // document.getElementById('AAI_Race_Span').classList.remove("campuri-necesare");
    // document.getElementById('AAI_Gender_span').classList.remove("campuri-necesare");

    document.getElementById('whatGender').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('whatGenderMale').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('whatGenderFemale').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('whatRace').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('AAI_White').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('AAI_Black').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('AAI_PacificIslander').disabled = true;
    etc etc etc.....
```

Comment: use jQuery's `removeClass()`. DOM traversal is a lot easier in jQuery as well, might as well stick to it.

Comment: jsfiddle this, please. It's pretty messy.

Comment: I highly recommend reading up on jQuery's selectors and learning how to use them. See here for some basics: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp This is very messy code, and it will be cleaned up significantly if you learn to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: give all checkboxes you want disabled by no self-identifocation condition a class such as `identity-checkbox`. Then the jquery you want is as simple as `$(".identity-checkbox").attr("disabled",true)`.